# I can copy to remote computer but cannot copy from using Python

Tags: python

Any ideas on why I cannot copy from remote computer?
The first snippet works and I can copy to the 'servername'.
The second snippet gives me a 'No such file or directory.' error when I want to copy from 'servername' to my local computer.

**UPDATE 2**

This does not work either...

```
def copyfrom():

    source_path = "\\computername\c$\test"
    dest_path= "C:\localtest"
    file_name = "testfile.txt"

    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source_path, file_name), os.path.join(dest_path, file_name))
```

**UPDATE** I'm reading that you cannot copy from a remote computer using shutil.  Anyone have any ideas on what my options are?

I have been copying to a list of computers using this...

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import re  
import sys  # some of these use for other code in my program

source = os.listdir("C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/") 
destination = '//' + servername + r'/c$/test/' 
for files in source:
    if files.endswith("myname.config"):
        try:
            os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)
            shutil.copy(files,destination)
        except:
            copyerror()


os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:
    copyfiles(servername.strip())
```

Why is the opposite not working?
Here is what I am trying:

```
def copyfrom(servername):
    # copy config from server


    source = os.listdir('//' + servername + r'/c$/test') # directory where original configs are located
    destination = 'C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/' # destination server directory
    for files in source:
        if files.endswith("myname.config"):
            try:
                os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)
                shutil.copy(files,destination)
            except:
                copyerror()  
    readconfig(servername)


# begin here
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:

        copyfrom(servername.strip())
```

Comment: I think your code is A) not properly indented, B) missing something (at least in the first snippet). Please fix.

Comment: what do you mean not working? do you get an error? what is the error?
also - why do you have 2 functions that do pretty much the same, you could write one function that takes different arguments like destination and source, that way you can be sure they really are the same

Comment: first snippet works  Sorry, I'm not getting an indention error.  I'm getting an error that says "No such file or directory" and after further reading, it looks like you cannot use shutil to copy files remotely.  You can only copy to a remote computer.

Comment: Ofer Sadan.  I was wanting to switch roles.  In the first snipet, I copied to 'servername' from my local computer.  In the second snipet, I wanted to copy to my local computer from the 'servername'.  Now I am reading that it may not be possible with shutil.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: What line is failing? What's the full error and stack trace?

Comment: @Prox How did you conclude that `shutil` can't do what you want it to do?

Comment: See 3rd party library [win_unc](https://covenanteyes.github.io/py_win_unc/)

Comment: It gives me an error that says "Cannot connect to remotecomputername"  I can switch source and destination directories and it works. (if the destination is the remote computer)  But I cannot copy from the remote computer

Comment: Don't edit "(solved)" into titles here -- checking the box on an answer (as you've done) is what flags a question solved. Similarly, don't edit solutions into questions -- if no answer solves your problem, encourage its author to edit it, or add a new answer yourself. Editing an answer into a question prevents the question and its answer from being voted on, reviewed, flagged, commented on, &c. separately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not running the script from a directory called C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/ by any chance?

os.listdir would be giving you the names of the entries in a directory at the specified path, not the full network name including the path.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

the modified example is using backslashes instead of forward slashes. if you want to do that, it's easier to use raw strings.

```
def copyfrom():

    source_path = r"\\computername\c$\test"
    dest_path= r"C:\localtest"
    file_name = "testfile.txt"

    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source_path, file_name), os.path.join(dest_path, file_name)
```

that said, there's really no reason to use backslashes in path names. unless you're running on a windows PC with no network share support, forward slash will be treated the same as backslash.

Comment: hmmm I used forward slashes in my newest update example and it works

Comment: shutil.copyfile cannot copy remote file to remote server.I used shutil.copy2 but it copy only local file so I cannot able to copy remote file to remote server any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @ArunKumar afraid I don't understand what you're saying there. I don't think shutil.copyfile knows anything about NTFS or any other local file system. It won't even know whether the file it is copying is local or remote, it would just need to be direclty accessible. See here for an example of making remote files accessible http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/